# No account for team "SFJHSFJ". Add a new account in the Accounts preference pane or verify that your accounts have valid credentials

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native, apple-developer-account

I was using my personal account to run the app in my simulator, Recently my organization send me an invite to join the team, I accepted and joined, but still, the team is unknown,How to solve the issue

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Go to `build settings`

Search for `signing`

You will find `Development Team` under `Signing`

Then change it to your own account and rebuild your project

Answer (score 0):

Change the team and bundle identifier in the debug and release tab of signing and capabilities section.